# Partial Order over an equivalence relation

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory

I have this Definition of Partial order:

> A binary relation $R$ in $A$ which is **reflexive**, **antisymmetric**
>   and 
>   **transitive** is called a **(partial) ordering** of $A$. The pair $(A, R)$ is called an ordered set.

Also,

> A binary relation $R$ in $A$ is **antisymmetric** if for all $a, b\in
> A$,  $aRb$ and $bRa$ imply $a = b$.

(From Introduction to Set theory by Hrbaceck, K., and Jech T.)

Now, my question is about the case when instead of equality we just have an equivalence relation. Like for example when we are dealing with geometry and the relation of congruence. So we define $\overline{ab}\preccurlyeq\overline{cd}$ if there existe $x\in \overleftrightarrow{ab}$ such that $a*b*x$ and $\overline{ax}\cong \overline{cd}$, or $\overline{ab}\cong\overline {cd}$. In this case the properties of being reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive follow over the relation of congruence instead of equality. Is it valid to call it a partial order? What is special of defining a partial order in terms of equality instead of equivalence relations?. Sorry if I'm so naive on this but I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 1):

The modified definition on some fixed equivalence relation is equivalent to defining a partial order on a quotient set.  Notice that the relation you give above becomes the order $\le$ when you take the lengths of line segments (and the equivalence relation you give partitions line segments into those that have equal length).